# Capturing some clicks, not all

Tags: javascript, jquery, delegates, jquery-events

I have built a modal box, which uses a cover-all div background to fade out the content and allow the user to click off the box in order to close it. I do this by capturing all of the clicks, but filtering out any that are over the model box.

```
  $('body').on('click', '.cover_slide > *',function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
  $('body').on('click', '.cover_slide',function(){
    helper.cover.close();
    $('body').off('click', '.cover_slide');
  });
```

I would like to be able to interact with some elements on my modal box with clicks, but I can't seem to figure out how to do that AND still have my 'click off to close' function. At present all clicks on the box are ignored.

Comment: What is your HTML for fade out background and popup body itself?

Comment: Can't you just detect a click on only the "cover-all" div background to close it?

Comment: no, because the cover-all background div is beneath the cover, so click events are not propagating from anything contained within the coverslide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to bind the click multiple times. Try using this snippet. Note that you might have to change the closest selector depending on what the element really is

```
$(document).bind("click", function(e) {
    if($(e.target).closest("div").hasClass('coverSlide')) {
        //do stuff if someone clicks the box
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm confused. Does this allow for closing when clicking on coverSlide away from coverSlides child elements?

Comment: Yes, this $(e.target).closest("div").hasClass('coverSlide') line detects whether its the coverSlide element (or its children) that got clicked.

Comment: it doesn't seem to differentiate between them, however.

Comment: It is a snippet,not a complete solution. This is to show you that there is no need to do multiple click binds. You're supposed to tailor the conditions to whatever you need.

Comment: I understand that. What I am saying is that this I am struggling to see how this will support my central requirement, which is to find clicks that are on the background div, and not its children.